# Which "nice question" has the highest votes/views ratio?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Just out of curiosity...

> **Question**:  Which "nice question" (i.e., one with a score of 10 or more) has the highest votes/views ratio?

The highest votes/views ratio I found was [Hyperbolic critters studying Euclidean geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/hyperbolic-critters-studying-euclidean-geometry) with a whopping 6.36%.

(Is there an easy way to find this?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some data.SE queries, e.g. [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/17776/top-votes-per-view). You can also run it for other sites, e.g. [our meta](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematicsmeta/query/17776/top-votes-per-view).

If you want, you can try to create your own queries. (You have to keep in mind that the data there are from the last dump which is already a few months old. What I was able to find about schedule of data dumps is [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106402/release-schedule-for-the-data-dump).)

Within the last data dump, the query returns this question (for MSE): [Do we really know the reliability of PrimeQ[n] (for $n>10^{16}$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123465/do-we-really-know-the-reliability-of-primeqn-for-n1016)
Votes per view ration is calculated as 0.245 from 23 upvotes and 93 views. (Obviously, the numbers have changed a little since then.)

I am not sure I understand the code of that query, since I don't see there PostTypeId=1. AFAIK this would correspond to selecting only questions and not all posts. (But I know very little about SQL and about data.SE, so the fact that I don't understand it should not be that surprising.)

Comment: Thanks for that; I haven't encountered that site before.

Comment: This really does highlight some good questions!

Comment: PostTypeId=1 is not needed because only questions have a number entered in the ViewCount column.